# Why is SQL Server changing operation order and boxing the way it does?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Four simple SELECT statements:

```
SELECT 33883.50 * -1;
SELECT 33883.50 / -1.05;
SELECT 33883.50 * -1 / 1.05;
SELECT (33883.50 * -1) / 1.05;
```

But the results are not as I would expect:

```
-33883.50
-32270.000000
-32269.96773000
-32270.000000
```

That third result is the one that seems questionable.  I can see what is happening, first SQL Server evaluates this:

```
SELECT -1 / 1.05;
```

Getting an answer of:

```
-0.952380
```

Then it takes that answer and uses it to perform this calculation:

```
SELECT 33883.50 * -0.952380;
```

To get the (wrong) answer of:

```
-32269.96773000
```

But why is it doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example

```
33883.50 * -1 / 1.05
```

is evaluated as

```
33883.50 * (-1 / 1.05)
```

instead of

```
(33883.50 * -1) / 1.05
```

which results in a loss in precision.

I played a bit with it. I used SQL Sentry Plan Explorer to see the details of how SQL Server evaluates expressions. For example,

```
2 * 3 * -4 * 5 * 6
```

is evaluated as

```
((2)*(3)) * ( -((4)*(5))*(6))
```

I'd explain it like this. In T-SQL unary minus is made to be the [same priority as subtraction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx), which is lower than multiplication. Yes,

> When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence
>   level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the
>   expression.

, but here we have an expression that mixes operators with different priorities and parser follows these priorities to the letter. Multiplication has to go first, so it evaluates `4 * 5 * 6` at first and then applies unary minus to the result.

Normally ([say in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)) unary minus has higher priority (like bitwise NOT) and such expressions are parsed and evaluated as expected. They should have made unary minus/plus same highest priority as bitwise NOT in T-SQL, but they didn't and this is the result. So, it is not a bug, but a bad design decision. It is even documented, though quite obscurely.

When you refer to Oracle - that the same example works differently in Oracle than in SQL Server:

- Oracle may have different [rules for operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) than SQL Server. All it takes is to make unary minus highest priority as it should.
- Oracle may have different [rules for determining result precision and scale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) when evaluating expressions with `decimal` type.
- Oracle may have different rules for rounding intermediate results. [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) "uses rounding when converting a number to a decimal or numeric value with a lower precision and scale".
- Oracle may be using completely different types for these kind of expressions, not `decimal`. In [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) "a constant with a decimal point is automatically converted into a numeric data value, using the minimum precision and scale necessary. For example, the constant 12.345 is converted into a numeric value with a precision of 5 and a scale of 3."
- Even definition of `decimal` may be different in Oracle. Even in [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) "the default maximum precision of numeric and decimal data types is 38. In earlier versions of SQL Server, the default maximum is 28."

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer.  I think this covers the reason for the anomaly, which was the whole point of my question.  So I am accepting this as the best answer :D

Comment: My pleasure. I once again confirmed that Plan Explorer is a great tool. Besides, I learned all these details how `decimal` type works in T-SQL. Bottom line: **T-SQL is not C++**. After this I think I should review my T-SQL code for accounting calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know **[*BODMAS*](http://www.math-only-math.com/bodmas-rule.html)** rule. The answer is correct its not because of Sql Server, Its a basic mathematics.

First comes `Division` then comes the `Subtraction`, So always Division will happen before Subtraction

If you want to get correct answer then use proper parenthesis

```
SELECT (33883.50 * -1) / 1.05;
```

Comment: It is not subtraction, it is the negative unary operator (-) (subtraction from zero if you will) but you are right according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) negative operator comes after division in execution order.

Comment: Agreed, subtraction comes after division.  But as Blim says there is no subtraction in my SQL statement.  BODMAS is fine, but it doesn't cope with defining precedence at the same "level".  In my example there is multiplication and division.  According to BODMAS it might appear that Multiplication ("Of") comes before Division, but this isn't true, they actually have the same precedence.

Comment: Okay, so I read the MSDN article again.  The negative operator does come after division in the operator order, so your answer does sort of make sense.  However, this isn't a basic mathematics problem, the answer should be the same regardless of precedence.  What is happening is that SQL Server is rounding the partial result and then getting the wrong answer as the final result.  There should, in theory, be no need for brackets as can be shown by running the same queries against an Oracle 11g database - where they all return the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL has an rule for operator precedence which it follows. You can read about it on the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx.

It seems to be a precedence rule concerning unary operators. I have tried the following queries

```
SELECT 33883.50 * cast(-1 as int) / 1.05;
SELECT 33883.50 * (-1 * 1)  / 1.05;
```

and it returns the right answer. The best thing to do is to use parentheses on expressions you want to occur first, and test thoroughly.

Comment: The documentation appears to be wrong, though, or at least leaves out the fact that different rounding and precision can take place depending on the operations involved. For example, it says that for all operators at the same level (e.g. multiplication and division), the operators will be processed left-to-right. That [does not explain this behavior very well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/236).

Comment: Interestingly (but not surprisingly), changing that SQL Fiddle to run against Oracle (which requires adding the "FROM DUAL" keywords) gives the same result regardless of the bracketing.

Comment: It seems to be a unary operator precedence. Oracle has it in its docs,  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators001.htm#SQLRF51150 . This does not fully explain why it behaves that way though

Comment: @AaronBertrand, [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) explains how SQL Server determines precision and scale of `decimal` type in calculations. Here we have a classic example of loss of precision. When dividing 1 by a number close to 1 `(1/1.05)` you need much more than (default) 6 decimal places to get accurate enough result if you intend to multiply it to a large number. When dividing large number 33883.50 by 1.05 default rules for calculating precision and scale of the result appear to be working good enough. So, order of operations does matter here.

Comment: @Vladimir I understand why there's a loss of precision. I just feel the behavior here doesn't match the order of operations the documentation describes. `a*b/c` should behave the same as `(a*b)/c`, but in this case it behaves like `a*(b/c)`. There is probably a reason SQL Server doesn't go strictly left to right here, but the documentation doesn't explain it as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I see. To me it looks like a bug. Doc is clear: "When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the expression", but here it doesn't work like it. **But** `33883.50 * (-1) / 1.05` is evaluated as  `(33883.50 * -1) / 1.05`. Go figure. It must be this unary minus operator that interferes somehow. **Aha!** SQL Sentry Plan Explorer gives an insight. It turns out that `33883.50 * -1 / 1.05` is evaluated as `(33883.50) * (-(1)/(1.05))`, but `33883.50 * (-1) / 1.05` <=> `((33883.50)*(-1))/(1.05)`

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I played a bit with it. `2 * 3 * -4 * 5 * 6` is evaluated as `((2)*(3))*( -((4)*(5))*(6))`. I'd explain it like this: they made unary minus to be the same priority as subtraction, which is lower than multiplication and parser follows these priorities to the letter. Normally (say in C++) unary minus is higher priority (like bitwise NOT) and such expressions are parsed as expected. They should have made unary minus/plus same highest priority as bitwise NOT in T-SQL, but they didn't and this is the result. So, it is not a bug, but a bad design decision.

Comment: @Vladimir I'd be inclined to agree that it's not a bug in the code, but it could certainly be considered to be a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I've added my findings as an answer. Strictly speaking it is not a bug, "it is a feature" - implementation does what is written in the documentation. The problem is that this "feature" is not what you expect, because it works differently than in other programming languages.